# No result in the table after executing INSERT in Python SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I used Python and the package SQLite to create table and insert data into the table. However, there is nothing in the table after I fired the execution. Can anyone help me figure it out? Thanks.

```
def conSqlite():
  conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\jet.cai\Documents\Logsitic.db')
  json_path = r'C:\Users\jet.cai\PycharmProjects\VJSF\txtToJson.json'
  try:
      create_table = ('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CODE2
          (Delivery            TEXT,
          Customer_Name        NCHAR(50),
          Shipment_Priority    TEXT
          )''')
      conn.execute(create_table)
  except:
      print("Table Failed")
      return False

  with open(json_path, 'r') as jsonf:
      lines = json.load(jsonf)
      for line in lines:
          sql = "insert into CODE2(Delivery,Customer_Name,Shipment_Priority) values('%s','%s','%s')"%(line['Delivery'],line['Customer Name'],line['Shipment Priority'])

          conn.execute(sql)


  # No results can be selected out
  df = pd.read_sql("select Delivery from CODE2", conn)

  print(df)
```

Comment: `commit` is a very important concept to keep in mind when dealing with a database.

Comment: Guys, I figured it out, I didn't commit the insert action, sorry for any bothering if occurs

Comment: Hi Alan, exactly, thanks for the comments!

Comment: we saw it at the same time.  its all good.

Comment: Stack should allow us to thumbsUp :)